# Esiste il modo di dire "fare il gambero"? Cosa significa?

Tags: idioms, meaning

Esiste il modo di dire "fare il gambero"? Cosa significa?

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te*, di Paola Mastrocola, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Gelsa le chiese se era pazza, e cosa stava facendo,  se le pareva il caso di andare a parlare con tutta quella gente vent'anni dopo, cosa s'era messa in testa di fare? *Il gambero*? Fil era quello che era, ma soprattutto era suo figlio,  lei lo sapeva benissimo che figlio aveva, e che la smettesse di andarlo a chiedere agli altri, camminando all'indietro, poi era il colmo!

Il testo si riferisce a una donna che, per cercare di saperne di più di suo figlio, è andata a visitare alcune delle persone che l'hanno frequentato nell'infanzia e nell'adolescenza.

Ho cercato il significato dell'espressione "fare il gambero" e ho trovato questo nel [dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/G/gambero.shtml):

> **fare come i gamberi** 
>   • **Fig**.: andare all'indietro, quindi peggiorare, regredire in generale. Più raramente, anche ritirarsi da un'impresa. 
>   Normalmente il gambero non procede a ritroso, ma in caso di pericolo spesso si flette e scatta all'indietro.

Tuttavia, non sono sicura che sia lo stesso del "fare il gambero" che appare nel brano sopra citato e che alcuno di questi significati figurati sia l'adatto al testo precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Io aggiungerei anche *essere un gambero*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrU9M6TSnPI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come hai evidenziato nella tua domanda, ***fare come i gamberi*** è un modo di dire che    si usa  quando uno torna indietro, sui propri passi, specialmente in senso figurato.
Nel brano il riferimento a tornare indietro dopo vent'anni a parlare con "tutta quella gente" viene inteso in questo senso. 
La donna in questione torna indietro nel tempo, va probabilmente a rivangare vecchie questioni che riguardano suo figlio.

Comment: E si può anche dire "fare il gambero"? O è necessariamente "fare come i gamberi"?

Comment: Entrambe vanno bene.

Comment: È curioso perché nella mia lingua (catalano) abbiamo un modo di dire simile, ma quelli che vanno all'indietro non sono i gamberi, ma i granchi. Possiamo dire: "anar com els crancs" oppure "anar enrere (o endarrere) com els crancs", cioè, "andare come i granchi" oppure "andare all'indietro come i granchi". Ma questi modi di dire si usano sempre col significato di peggiorare e mai nel senso di andare all'indietro nel tempo.

Comment: Anche in Italiano l'espressione ha una connotazione negativa, infatti nel brano viene usato in senso critico.